Why is a Na-K pump necessary if the neural membrane is impermeable to Na+ ions during the resting phase?
If the neural membrane is impermeable to Na+ ions during the resting phase, why does it require a Na-K pump to expel sodium ions? What causes the accumulation of Na+ ions inside the membrane if it is supposed to be impermeable to them?
Understanding this could shed light on the fundamental workings of neural cell physiology and ion regulation.
